# Exception Code 80000003 - First Assembly Program

Tags: exception, assembly, error-handling

After I tried to use a macro given by my instructor, my programs began to crash even after changing the body of the file. The report is giving Exception 80000003. The only info I can find on this relates to breakpoints and I don't see how I would have a breakpoint in my asm code. Any light on this matter would be great. Thanks.

Macros provided: debug.h

```
inputW          MACRO  prompt, location
               output prompt
               input text, 8
               atoi text
               mov location, ax
            ENDM

outputW     MACRO   var
               itoa text, var
               mov text + 6, 0
               output text
               output carriage
            ENDM
```

My Code:

```
.386
.MODEL FLAT

ExitProcess PROTO NEAR32 stdcall, dwExitCode:DWORD
INCLUDE ../debug.h

CR          EQU    0Dh  ; carriage return character
LF          EQU    0Ah  ; linefeed character

.STACK 4096

.DATA                 ;data storage
num       WORD  ?
prompt1   BYTE  "Enter a number:  ", 0

.CODE
_start:
        inputW prompt1, num 
        outputW num

        INVOKE  ExitProcess, 0 

PUBLIC _start
END
```

This code, nor any code will run without crashing with Exception 80000003

Comment: Have you tried debugging the code with turboDebugger or some other asm debugger?

Comment: I will do that now. I noticed that when this error occurs, if I comment out the lines I just entered, change my make file in some way, try to re-make, fix my make file an then make, the problem fixes and I can then add in the lines of code I desire. This is very gimmicky, does this info help at all?

Comment: Here is my make file.

    @echo off
    cls

    path = "c:\CSC 3410\masm"

    ml -Zi -c -coff -Fl cameras.asm
    link cameras.obj ../io.obj ../kernel32.lib /out:cameras.exe /debug /subsystem:console /entry:start
    cameras

Comment: One more note, this only happens whenever I add in a new inputW statement

Comment: Are you writing assembly, or inventing a new language and implementing it with macros? Excessive use of macros does nothing more than obfusticate the code (if you don't see what I mean, try to find an "atoi" instruction in Intel's manuals).

Comment: First, in `_start:` you expand a macro `inputW`. But `inputW` expands other macros `output`, `input` and `atoi`. However, you haven't included the definitions of those macros in your question. As your code has `.386`, I assume this is for `x86`. Please add the definitions of macros `output`, `input` and `atoi` and please state which OS (eg. Linux, DOS, Windows) you are targeting, and should this be 32-bit or 64-bit code.